# Actual use of sparse voxel octrees in a game engine

Tags: voxels, octree, level-of-detail

Looking for different ways to speed up my simple voxel system reducing the number of voxels and generated triangles, I stumbled upon these **sparse voxel octrees**.
Now, I read a lot about it: how do they work, their implementation, pro and cons especially regarding level of detail (that was my research purpose).
I am not an experienced game developer at all, until now I managed to create a simple yet working procedural generation based on chunks, contoured with Marching Cubes. As many other voxel engines, every chunk is formed by a tridimensional array of voxels, where each one has a density value and a position. 
Before I even start trying to implement a Voxel Octree, my questions are:

1) How can I "translate" my world generation in order to use the octrees?

2) Should I use an octree **for every chunk**, or just **one octree** with "big" bounds **containing the whole generated data**?

3) Regarding my project, the aim is to create simple spherical world (fairly big, definitely too much without a LOD), **are Voxel Octrees even necessary** for my purpose?

Forgive my ignorance, I probably don't have the basic knowledge on these topics, but I still wanted to try this cool stuff.
Thanks!

Comment: I found [this voxel game engine](https://github.com/JosephKrusling/SparseVoxelRaytacer) on GitHub, but not much else (yet).